# Check if index exist when index is on multiple columns

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2017

We recently ran a missing index report on our system database and found that many were missing, but because our database can be different with regarding to indexes for each client we wanted to create a way to tell if an index exist already.

Many of our indexes can be on multiple columns, multiple columns with includes, single columns and single columns with includes.  Many times the indexes are added and we don't have a good tracking system of them and may not be named what we think they are.  With all that I need a way to check if an index already exist for the following conditions.

1. Does the name already exist?
2. Does an index already exist on the same table with the same indexed column with the same includes but by a different name?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: SQL SERVER 2017

Comment: I give my indexes canonical names (such as table_column_column).  That makes it pretty easy to scan index names to see what is present and absent.

Comment: Let's just say you should take Missing Index Suggestions from query plans with a pinch of salt. You may find [`sp_BlitzIndex` by Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) more useful

Answer (score 0):

To Check if index already exists

```
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('<your table name here>')
                AND name='<your index name here>')
```

This should give you all the indexes in a table with column name.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
    SELECT i.name AS index_name  
    ,COL_NAME(ic.object_id,ic.column_id) AS column_name  
    ,ic.index_column_id  
    ,ic.key_ordinal  
,ic.is_included_column  
FROM sys.indexes AS i  
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
    ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id  
WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('<your table here>')
```